# How to always send default parameters in HTTP request using Moya/Alamofire?

Tags: ios, swift, design-patterns, alamofire, moya

My server side **always** requires a client to send a token. As a developer, I can forget it. Now, I want to come up with some solution that forces me to not forget sending such a required parameters (they can grow in the future, for instance, server can require device's language). The solution seems pretty easy: I should have some `ServerManager` that gets a parameters (for instance, ["user": "John"]) and URL path. And it also should append required parameters, for example, ["token": "abscsdcds"]. The pseudocode would be something like following:

```
struct ServerManager {
     func request(params: [String: Any], path: String, completion: (ResponseModel) -> Void) {
          /// appending required default params 
          var paramsToSend = params
          paramsToSend["token"] = Token.token 

          /// making request here               

     }
}
```

Whenever I make network call, I can use that `ServerManager` with any doubt that sends all required params and return response.

But things gets complicated because I use `Moya` for networking. It is made by `enumerations` that should implement `TargetType` protocol. I can have dozens of `enums` like `RateAPI`, `MovieAPI` and etc... It means that my `ServerManager` should accept `TargetType` and HTTP request using `MoyaProvider`. Here it is:

```
 func request<T>(type: TargetType, completion: (ResponseModel<T>) -> Void) {
              /// appending required default params 
              moyaProvider.request(MultiTarget(type)) {  response in 
                     /// parse it 
              }              



         }
```

I can simple use above function passing `TargetType` and it returns me a response. I can use above function as following:

```
ServerManager.shared.request(target: MovieApi.list(params)) { (response) in

}
```

But `params` variable above should always contain token. It means that I should write `params["token"] = "myToken"` whenever I make network request. It is code duplication. I thought to create some base `RequestModel` that contains my required parameters. Then I can have different subclasses of `RequestModel` that appends its fields to required params. But this solution can be easily mislead (for instance, subclass can send its own parameters forgetting about parent class params).

It seems my problem in design. Are there any design pattern that solves problem above? Or do we have built in solution in Moya/Alamofire that sends some parameters by default to every request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually server api's get token from TTPHeaderFields and with Moya you can easily change your **defaultEndpointMapping** in Some class like **ApiGenerator** with some method like:

```
static func request<T : Decodable, E: TargetType>(targetApi : E, responseModel : T.Type, success successCallBack: @escaping (Response<T>) -> Void, error errorCallBack: @escaping (Error) -> Void) -> Disposable {
    ...

    }
```

And inside this method:

```
let endpointClosure = { (target: E ) -> Endpoint in
            let defaultEndpoint = MoyaProvider.defaultEndpointMapping(for: target)
            let cookie = String(format: "JSESSIONID=%@;SPRING_SECURITY_REMEMBER_ME_COOKIE=%@", AppSettings.shared.setting.sessionId, AppSettings.shared.setting.rememberMeCookie )


            return defaultEndpoint.adding(newHTTPHeaderFields:
                [
                    "X-Client": "ios",
                    "Cookie" : cookie
                ]
            )
        }
```

and add it to:

```
let provider = MoyaProvider<E>(endpointClosure: endpointClosure, plugins: [
            NetworkLoggerPlugin(configuration: .init(logOptions: .verbose))])
```

And do the rest. But in your case I recommend to create your ApiGenerator class and customize your **TargetApi.Task**  in it like this:

```
switch defaultEndpoint.task {
   case .requestParameters(parameters: /*Append new params here*/ , encoding: JSONEncoding.default):
       ...
    default:
       ...
 }
```

Comment: Can you clarify what is `defaultEndpoint` here? It seems all magic is there.

Comment: it is instance of MoyaProvider.defaultEndpointMapping. See my example Again (below  "And inside this method:")